# How to catch undefined macro in preprocessor #if condition?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Based on this question [How to catch empty defined macro with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335324/how-to-catch-undefined-preprocessor-macro-with-gcc/39335483#39335483) I have another problem. How to catch undefined macro in preprocessor `#if` condition? Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
#if ENABLE_SOMETHING == 1
    ... do something ..
#endif
 return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to catch error/warning when `ENABLE_SOMETHING` is not set using gcc compiler(maybe some flag)? Or maybe there are external tools which I can use?

---

I know than i can write something like this :

```
#ifndef ENABLE_SOMETHING
    #error "ENABLE_SOMETHING undefined!"
#endif
```

But I have a huge amount of different defines(`ENABLE_STH1`, `ENABLE_STH2`, `ENALBE_STH3` ... etc.) in code and i don't want to fix this manually. I'm looking for some automatic solution for our project.

Comment: You will get a pre-processor error if macro is not defines in above example. Something like this `error: 'MAX_N_LENGTH' undeclared`

Comment: If `MAX_N_LENGTH` is undefined then the compiler will not compile the code.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, wrong example. Wait a moment.

Comment: Are you saying that you have undefined tokens used in your code, and it's compiling? I don't understand this question.

Comment: Yes, I use these tokens to enable/disable some parts of code in diffrent build configurations. But i want to have some guard for future errors if somebody will make new #if but will forgot to add #define (which happend).

Comment: After the edit I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to use search & replace in your text editor? The only reliable way to get a compiler error is by using `#error` explicitly. No matter the solution, there's no way around modifying the code.

Comment: If you don't want to display an error but merely wish to make the code rugged, you can write `#if defined MAX_N_LENGTH && (MAX_N_LENGTH == 1)`.

Comment: Ok but as I said there is too many places to fix and other programmer could add new place and  add it wrongly, without `defined()`. I'm looking for automatic solution.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of conditional compilation that different compilations happen when different pre-processor identifiers are defined or not?? So you don't want this!

Comment: Why is this a problem at all? Do you rely on the difference between not being defined at all and being defined as 0 anywhere?

Comment: Because of human errors. Last week somebody added code  `#if ENABLE_STH1 == 1` and also added in configuration file 
`#ifndef STH1_ENABLE`
`#define STH1_ENABLE` 1
`#endif`
Problem was because in some build configurations(which needed `ENABLE_STH == 0` it was working as expected. But other configurations had error which was found by human test.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to catch error/warning when ENABLE_SOMETHING is not set
>   using gcc compiler(maybe some flag)?

With GCC you can use the `-Wundef` flag.

[From the official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> -Wundef
>
> Warn if an undefined identifier is evaluated in an #if directive. Such identifiers are replaced with zero.

***EDIT:***

For example, this C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#if UNDEFINED_MACRO
  printf("hi mum!\n");
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

... compiled with GCC and the -Wundef flag yields this:

```
$ gcc undef.c -Wundef
undef.c: In function 'main':
undef.c:5:5: warning: "UNDEFINED_MACRO" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #if UNDEFINED_MACRO
     ^
```

Comment: Ok, so -Wundef together with -Werror will give me an error, won't it?

Comment: @s.paszko: Yes. `-Werror` converts warnings into errors that makes compilation fail, so that would emit an error if the compiler encountered an undefined macro

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have this code and it compiles, but you don't know if `MAX_N_LENGTH` is a macro, or if it's something else:

```
int main()
{
    int a = MAX_N_LENGTH; // MAX_N_LENGTH could also be an int declared somewhere else
    return 0;
}
```

You can check whether it actually is a macro like this:

```
#ifdef MAX_N_LENGTH
    printf("MAX_N_LENGTH is a macro.\n");
#else
    printf("MAX_N_LENGTH is NOT macro.\n");
#endif // MAX_N_LENGTH
```

Of course, if that ever is an issue, I'd rethink my naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for question but i've gave wrong example. Question redited.

Comment: The same still applies, you can use `#ifdef ... #endif` to get conditional compilation depending on whether the macro in question exists or not.

Comment: Ok, added info in question. I know this solution but i'm looking for some automatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
#ifndef MAX_N_LENGTH
#warning "MAX_N_LENGTH is undefined"
    int array[16];
#else
    int array[MAX_N_LENGTH + 1];
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for question but i've gave wrong example. Question redited.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a macro is defined in a `#if` preprocessor expression with `defined(ENABLE_SOMETHING)`:

```
#if !defined(ENABLE_SOMETHING)
  #error ENABLE_SOMETHING is not defined
#endif
```

You can handle macros with an empty definition this way:

```
#if ENABLE_SOMETHING + 0 == 1
   /* ENABLE_SOMETHING is defined and not 0 or empty */
#endif
```